# Why javascript doesn't work when the site is online?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

On the following site : http://www.cefod.org/legitchad/web there are a lot of javascript (jquery, jquery-ui).

Everything is working *offline*, but when the website is online, no more script is working.

It seems there are no problem with the  tags, since you can read them by clicking on the links in the page's source.

So, what is the problem ?

Comment: Take a look at the JavaScript console, please. The jquery-ui.js file is corrupted (part of a comment on line 7199?)

Comment: Check your Firebug, there are errors..

Comment: thanks a lot ! I don't have Firebug since i can only upload the website on a cybercafé... Internet in Chad is _sooooooooo_ slowly...

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/firebug/) tells me your jquery-ui.js is broken in line 7199.

Looks like an encoding problem. Get a new file from the [jquery ui website](http://jqueryui.com/download). Make sure it not get's broken during the upload.

Answer (score 1):

I get 2 error messages when running you site through Firebug:

```
illegal character in jquery-ui.js on line 7199
$.datepicher is undefined in ui-datepicker-fr.js on line 2
```

Probably has something to do with you problems

Answer (score 0):

Inside your jquery-ui.js, there is something wrong on line: 7199, I see al lot of characters that can not be found, maybe something went wrong on uploading this file.

What if you try using this URL, just checking if this makes the error, this is not the newest jQueryUI url, but it's the same version as you are using now:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 0):

your file upload could have messed up,
did you try re-uploading?

because what I see in the file online at the mentioned lines above is "����������������������������������������..."

this could have happened if your transfer stopped and tried to resume